# android Webview use custom html file as container

Tags: android, html, parsing, webview

I want to keep every page loaded contained in my custom html file.

First my app should parse the page that has been loaded, then select body tag, and push into my custom html file, then show in WebView, and repeat.

I used `loadDataWithBaseURL("http://someurl", readFileAsString("index.html").replace("Content goes here", parsedtext) , "text/html", null, null)`

First loading was OK, but when I  clicked some links, the original page was loaded(not contained in my html)

I can't change the initial html design manually since they're from third parties.

Anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you need alse use method below:

```
wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            //do something...
            return true;
        }
    });    
wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //do something...
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem is that when I use `onPageStarted` or `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` or `onPageFinished` it just show the baseurl I entered in. So it can't get helped.